# Save/Load numpy array as column in Pandas to csv file

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, csv

I have the following DataFrame

```
index    word      decoded_Word                   language

0        potato    [17, 24,  1, 21,  1, 24]       english

1        animal    [21, 13, 23, 18, 21, 25]       english

2        שלום       ...                            hebrew
```

and I want to convert it to a csv file, i used the following line

```py
df.to_csv('dataset.csv',encoding='utf8',index=False)
```

and get the following file

```
potato,[17 24  1 21  1 24],english
animals,[21 13 23 18 21 25  4],english
שלום,[21 12  6 24],hebrew
```

but when I execute the following code I get

```py
data = pd.read_csv('dataset.csv')
print(type(data['decoded_word'][0]))
```

the result is `str`

I would like to know if there is better way to save/load the numpy array.

Thank you.

Comment: before saving are the type of  `print(type(df['decoded_Word'][0]))` is `<class 'numpy.ndarray'>`?

Comment: hi! Is any one of the answers below working? If so & if you wish, you might consider [accepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) one of them to signal others that the issue is resolved. If not, you can provide feedback so they can be improved (or removed altogether)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is normal, because pandas does not store the format of the columns in a csv file, and there is only so much it can infer.

To solve this simply, after loading the dataset (so after `data = pd.read_csv('dataset.csv')`) do:

```
data[decoded_word] = data[decoded_word].astype(list)
```

This will change the type of the column to `list`. You may be able to convert it to a `numpy.ndarray` as well.

An alternative, if this is possible for you, is to store the dataframe in another format, e.g., pickle:

```
data.to_pickle('dataset.pkl')
```

This should preserve the columns types.

Note: I see a comment indicating that you should use `eval`. This should work as well, but, as a rule, I prefer to never use eval for manipulating data unless it is the only way and you are very sure there is no security threat.

Answer (score 1):

Before saving change the type of 'decoded_Word' from `np.array` to `list` then save it to csv:

```
df['decoded_Word']=df['decoded_Word'].map(list)
#Finally save that csv:
df.to_csv('dataset.csv',encoding='utf8',index=False)
```

Now load that file:

```
data = pd.read_csv('dataset.csv')
#Since the 'decoded_Word' is string so make it real list by:
data['decoded_Word']=pd.eval(data['decoded_Word'])
#(optional if you need array then):
data['decoded_Word']=data['decoded_Word'].map(np.array)
```