# Pandas DataFrame Entry from Tuple to Array

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, dataframe, numpy

right now i have a DataFrame which contains in every row an entry with a Tuple containing Datas (20 Values per Tuple).

[DataFrame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HQdMI.png)

The tuple was created when trying to put an entire array into the appropriate row as an entry with the following line of code:

```
DataFrame=pd.DataFrame('windows20_energy_x': array_passed},dtype=float)
```

i already tried to add brackets like:

```
DataFrame=pd.DataFrame('windows20_energy_x': [array_passed]},dtype=float)
```

but get the error: AssertionError: Number of Block dimensions (4) must equal number of axes (2)

The array_passed:

```
[array([0.403, 0.153, 0.052, 0.299, 0.141, 0.056, 0.041, 0.019, 0.009,
       0.067, 0.05 , 0.022, 0.014, 0.054, 0.007, 0.007, 0.002, 0.009,
       0.003, 0.005]), array([0.277, 0.054, 0.101, 0.378, 0.066, 0.056, 0.047, 0.02 , 0.007,
       0.057, 0.036, 0.022, 0.024, 0.045, 0.006, 0.008, 0.007, 0.007,
       0.003, 0.002]), array([ 0.859,  1.905,  0.808,  9.338,  9.02 , 15.852,  2.491,  5.449,
        4.896,  5.937,  3.969,  3.397,  2.666,  0.429,  0.348,  0.458,
        0.527,  0.55 ,  0.234,  0.174]), array([0.489, 0.105, 0.089, 0.464, 0.145, 0.043,0.035, 0.008, 0.012,
       0.03 , 0.046, 0.019, 0.017, 0.194, 0.005, 0.014, 0.013, 0.009,
       0.007, 0.005])]
```

- Is it possible to convert the tuple into arrays (So that the frame eventually contains arrays and not tuples)?

or

- Is there maybe another approach to get the DataFrame directly in the right way with arrays containing (By appropriate improvement/adjustment of the code line)?

Thanks in advance for your Answers!

Comment: Your code contains errors. Please add the missing `{` and check your code runs. Also please provide values for `array_passed` (not a screenshot image) so we can reproduce your results.

Answer (score 3):

Pass `dtype=object` when creating the dataframe:

```py
DataFrame = pd.DataFrame({"windows20_energy_x": array_passed}, dtype=object)
print(type(DataFrame.loc[0, "windows20_energy_x"]))
```

Prints:

```
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! with changing the dtype to object it works!:-)

Comment: Another Question. If i save the DataFrame as CSV and reload it again into the Notebook the dtypes of the Columns is "object". When i have a closer look i regognize that all Entrys (so all the Arrays) are String values instead of arrays (print('type col ',type(DataFrame_All_Datas['windows20_energy_x'][0])) ---> i get type col  <class 'str'>) Do you know whats the reason therefore? Thanks in Advance!

Comment: @CarstenWE The reason is CSV format doesn't store type of columns (in this case numpy.ndarray). Everything is stored as text. You need to do conversion to correct manually when loading from CSV to Pandas.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Is there a command for convert the dtype directly during the reload with pd.read_csv ?

Comment: @CarstenWE Look at `dtype=` and `converters=` parameter in [`pd.read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html)

Comment: Yes, thanks. I already tried but unfortunately it doesn't work. i used DataFrame=pd.read_csv('file.csv',convert={'windows20_energy_x':np.float}) and got the error message --> ValueError: could not convert string to float: '[6.457e+00 8.000e-03 9.000e-03 1.330e-01 2.000e-03 1.000e-03 2.000e-03\n 1.000e-03 1.000e-03 6.000e-03 1.000e-03 1.000e-03 0.000e+00 1.000e-03\n 0.000e+00 0.000e+00 0.000e+00 0.000e+00 0.000e+00 0.000e+00]'.  I got the same Message when i use DataFrame=pd.read_csv('file.csv', dtype={'windows20_energy_x':np.float})

Comment: @CarstenWE Try this answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68336649/save-load-numpy-array-as-column-in-pandas-to-csv-file (basically - do a conversion after loading from csv. Also store the values as Python's list not a numpy array). Or use different format than csv.

Answer (score 0):

If I make a frame from a list of 3 arrays:

```
In [398]: df = pd.DataFrame({'foo':[np.arange(3),np.ones(3),np.zeros(3)]})
In [399]: df
Out[399]: 
               foo
0        [0, 1, 2]
1  [1.0, 1.0, 1.0]
2  [0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
In [400]: df.to_numpy()
Out[400]: 
array([[array([0, 1, 2])],
       [array([1., 1., 1.])],
       [array([0., 0., 0.])]], dtype=object)
```

If I do the same, but specify `dtype=float`, as you do:

```
In [401]: df = pd.DataFrame({'foo':[np.arange(3),np.ones(3),np.zeros(3)]}, dtype=float)
In [402]: df
Out[402]: 
               foo
0        (0, 1, 2)
1  (1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
2  (0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
In [403]: df.to_numpy()
Out[403]: 
array([[(0, 1, 2)],
       [(1.0, 1.0, 1.0)],
       [(0.0, 0.0, 0.0)]], dtype=object)
```

It's still not not `float` dtype, but apparently it has tried some sort of conversion.  Filling dataframe columns with objects - arrays, lists, tuples or whatever, deviates in to one degree or other from the basic dataframe 2d character.